# In Corda, what makes contracts legally binding?

Tags: corda

I have a question regarding the following part of the [Corda introductory whitepaper](https://www.corda.net/content/corda-platform-whitepaper.pdf) (from section `3.1 - End-State Principles`):

> Legal footing. Deals recorded by the ledger are, by contract, accepted
>   as admissible evidence and legally binding by all parties in any
>   dispute.

The footnote in the whitepaper links to a document entitled `The Ricardian Contract`, but I'm not fully understanding the correlation. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is, of course, nothing purely technological that can magically make something legally binding. So you're right to be sceptical! Instead, what we're trying to deliver with Corda is a set of tools that enables people *using* the platform to form legally binding agreements.

Ian Grigg is the authority on this subject. But the idea is this: how do we enable two or more parties to apply a digital signature to a chunk of information and, in the future, be able to use that information and those signatures to convince a judge to rule on a dispute should one arise?

Well... we'd need some way of showing that those signatures did indeed belong to those they purport to be from (hence Corda's identity layer and PKI, etc). But we'd also need to deal with the fact that, no matter how hard one might try, a collection of fields in a Java object and a chunk of associated code is never going to be able to capture the full intent of a legal agreement.

And so we *also* need the ability to have that signed electronic document *reference* an overarching prose legal agreement. That agreement (which you have to write yourself of course - it will differ based on the context), will effectively say:

> "The parties to this agreement, who signal their assent through the
>   application of digital signatures on a Corda data object that
>   references this document's hash and whose identities are authenticated
>   by the following identity service PKI, agree to be bound by the
>   following terms..."

And those terms, in turn, will specify which parts of the agreement are captured by (and perhaps delegated to) data structures + code... and which ones are not automated in code and are captured only in the prose.

There's nothing forcing you to use this model but we want to make sure we provide all the pieces for those who do.